# Trouble understanding solution for New Years Chaos on Hackerrank (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

The problem can be found [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/new-year-chaos/problem)

I struggled with this for quite some time - and I've always neglected learning CS related material in Javascript or in general. But I will be interviewing at some different companies and some have notified that the tech interview will be data structure/algorithm related, so I'm currently going through some courses online and completing challenges on Hackerrank.

Anyway - I eventually caved after a few hours and looked up some solutions.
One being this:

```js
let queue1 = [2, 1, 5, 3, 4];
let queue2 = [2, 5, 1, 3, 4]; 

function minimumBribes(q) {
  let bribes = 0;
  let currentIndex = q.length - 1;
  let positionDiff;

  while (currentIndex >= 0) {
    const currentValue = q[currentIndex];
    const valuePosition = currentIndex + 1;
    positionDiff = currentValue - valuePosition; 

    if (positionDiff >= 3) {
      return "Too chaotic";
    }

    const briberPosition = currentValue - 2;
    for (let comparePosition = Math.max(0, briberPosition); comparePosition < currentIndex; comparePosition++) {
      const compare = q[comparePosition];

      if (compare > currentValue) {
        bribes++;
      }
    }
    currentIndex--;
  }

 return bribes;
}

minimumBribes(queue1)
```

I understand that we need to check if a number has moved forward more than 2 spaces, and checking its value vs position does this.
However, getting to

```js
const briberPosition = currentValue - 2;
for (let comparePosition = Math.max(0, briberPosition); comparePosition < currentIndex; comparePosition++) { ... }
```

is leaving me confused. I've ran through this slowly in debugger with different values and I can't wrap my head around why we set the currentValue - 2 to the briberPosition, and then checking that vs the index.

Could someone share some light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final question of the challenge is "HOW MANY bribes are needed to get the queue into this state".

So he chose to go from the end on every number and first checks if its 3 or more places ahead of its original position- this part you already got.

Now, if its not 3 or more places away- you want to know HOW many places away, this can be done simply by going 2 places back, and check if the numbers 2 places away and 1 place away are greater than the value in our current position. If they are- it means they bribed him to get there so we increment the "bribes" variable and go on to the next integer and repeat the process. Since he goes at the array from the end, he decrements the position to get to the farthest place a "briber" of our current value can be.

If it helps, this whole `for` loop can be completely skipped when `positionDiff` is 0, if he checked that after the `too chaotic` check, it could be a little more efficient.

Notice that in the "for" loop he trims it to be the `Math.max(0, briberPosition)` to avoid going beyond array limit.